# Setting a cell to a value of another cell IF another cell was value X

Tags: excel

Is there a formula in excel to allow you to obtain the value of another cell WHEN a second cell was value X?

For example, something like:

```
=GETWHEN(A1,3,B2)
```

Which would return B2's cell value when A1 is value 3.

So if let's say you had a cell B2=4*B1. And B1 you set to 3, so B2 would show 12. But I want to make a row of entries to plot what B2 will be when A1 is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc...

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/21eua80.png]

What could I put under A1 Values?

EDIT: I'm not looking for a if like in the conditional sense. I'm looking for the value WHEN (edited now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about [data tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-one-variable-data-table-HP005199545.aspx).

Provided you have your values in `E2:E6`, and your formula in `B2`:

- Enter `=B2` in cell F1.
- Select `E1:F6`.
- Go `Data - Data table` and put `B1` into the `Row input cell` box (B1 being the cell on which B2 depends).